# how can you interleave two vectors of differing lengths in clojure

Tags: clojure

What is the simplest way to interleave two vectors with `n+1`  and `n` members?

```
(def a [:a :c :e])
(def b [:b :d])
(interleave a b ); truncates to shortest list
[:a :b :c :d]

;what I would like. 
(interleave-until-nil a b)
[:a :b :c :d :e]
```

Comment: In this specific case, you can just do `(concat (interleave a b) [(last a)])`

Comment: @zack Will you have varying lengths on the vectors? Your example shows one but if you want something generic to handle any two vectors of any length please comment.

Comment: Take a look at [medley](https://github.com/weavejester/medley). It contains an [interleave-all](https://weavejester.github.io/medley/medley.core.html#var-interleave-all) function that does what you want.

Comment: @FrankC. In my scenario I am using `partition-all` to split a sequence, applying a function to the odd/even values and recombining the sequence. If the original sequence is even I would have two vectors of the same length. If the original vector is odd the first sequence will be longer than the second by one member.

Comment: thanks @sloth - thats  nice little library.

Comment: IMO If you instead asked for "vectors of differing lengths", both the question and the answers would be way more helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cons the first, interleave the rest with arguments reversed.

```
(cons (first a) (interleave b (rest a)))
;=> (:a :b :c :d :e)
```

Answer (score 2):

Conj nil to the second, interleave colls get all butlast

```
(butlast (interleave a (conj b nil)))
;=> (:a :b :c :d :e)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn interleave+ [& x] 
  (take (* (count x) (apply max (map count x))) 
    (apply interleave (map cycle x))))

(butlast (interleave+ [:a :c :e] [:b :d]))
=> (:a :b :c :d :e)
```

Comment: I fear you should explain / elaborate to avoid deletion.

Answer (score 2):

Tried this as an exercise in lazy seqs. I suspect that there are more elegant ways though.

```
(defn interleave-all
  "interleaves including remainder of longer seqs."
  [& seqs]
  (if (not-empty (first seqs))
    (cons (first (first seqs)) (lazy-seq (apply interleave-all (filter not-empty (concat (rest seqs) [(rest (first seqs))])))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to have `nil` appended to always have same dimension results, this could be a way to do that:

```clj
(defn interleave-all [& seqs]
  (reduce
   (fn [a i]
     (into a (map #(get % i) seqs)))
   []
   (range (apply max (map count seqs)))))
```

For example:

```clj
(interleave-all [:a] [:b :c])
```

outputs:

```clj
[:a :b nil :c]
```

This can be used to transpose a matrix:

```clj
(defn matrix-transpose [input]
  (partition
   (count input)
   (apply interleave-all input)))
```

Example:

```clj
(matrix-transpose [[:a] [:b :c]])
```

Outputs:

```clj
[[:a :b] [nil :c]]
```

Which can be used to i.e. tabular output of lists of differing lengths (but where you need the fixed dimensions to insert nothing where lists have no value for certain indices).

Comment: Needed to change to `(map #(get (vec %) i) seqs))` to make it work with lists.